# Python pyc files created with root as owner

Tags: python, cron

I have a python program, stored on Dropbox, which runs via cron on a couple of different machines. For some reason, recently one of the .pyc files is being created with root as the owner, which means that Dropbox doesn't have permission to sync it anymore.

Why would it do that, and how do I change it?

Answer (score 1):

That would happen if you're running the python program as `root` (which would happen if you're using `root`'s crontab).
To fix it, just remove it with `sudo rm /path/to/file.pyc`, and make sure to run the program as your user next time. If you want to keep using `root`'s crontab, you could use `su youruser -c yourprogram`, but the cleanest way would be simply to use your user's crontab

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. Does cron run as root? I don't think I've ever run it as root...

Comment: @Jeremy each user can have their own jobs on cron. You should `man crontab`. You can also check the [Ubuntu's cron howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Comment: It looks like I've been using my crontab, not root's.

Comment: @Jeremy maybe you ran the program manually as root then? You'll have to figure out what caused the problem next time it happens.

Comment: Ok - I'll try to do some more debugging. I figured running it as root was the only way for that to happen - good to get confirmation. Thanks!